# Different between "|" and [superview] in Visual Format Language?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, visual-format-language

Here is a [example](https://github.com/evgenyneu/center-vfl/blob/master/CenteringWithVFL/ViewController.swift) in github set view programly in the center of the superview.

```
constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
      "H:[superview]-(<=1)-[label]",
      options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterY,
      metrics: nil,
      views: ["superview":view, "label":label])
```

My question is ,while I replaced the "[superview]" with "|", like apple document explain, I guess they are equals. Actually they're not,
and it will not work.

my code.

```
   constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
                    "H:|-(<=1)-[imageview]",
                    options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterY,
                    metrics: nil,
                    views: ["imageview":imageview])
```

is there anything wrong ,or a bug with VFL?
apple document [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original code uses a trick (or a hack).

`AlignAllCenterY` was not meant to center views within the container. The options are there to specify the relative position of the subviews - for example, if you have 3 labels in the same container, you can make them all top aligned or center aligned between themselves - not with the container (implicitly specified by `|`).

The trick is that when you specify the superview explicitly, the framework doesn't realize it a adds the constraints.

The correct way to center a view in its container is the following:

```
let centerX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, 
                            attribute: .CenterX, 
                            relatedBy: .Equal,
                               toItem: view,
                            attribute: .CenterX, 
                           multiplier: 1.0,        
                             constant: 0.0);
view.addConstraint(centerX);

let centerY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, 
                            attribute: .centerY, 
                            relatedBy: .Equal,
                               toItem: view,
                            attribute: .centerY, 
                           multiplier: 1.0,        
                             constant: 0.0);
view.addConstraint(centerY);
```

Comment: Sorry. Still not clear to understand,what's the different between "|" and superview? and may I use constraintsWithVisualFormat to get this requirement.NSLayoutConstraint init() is a little complex?

Comment: Do you mean "|" will not taken by NSLayoutFormatOptions as  a child of "All",but [superview] wil be taken as a member of "AlignAllCenterY"?

Comment: @Albert.Qing Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

```
constrains.append(contentsOf: NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-[personImage(==50)]", options: [.alignAllCenterY], metrics: nil, views: views))
```

if personImage is by himself nothing will happen.

If you have multipleviews inside H:| | then you can use .alignAllCenterY

if you need to align one view to his superview use Sulthan answer. Thank you
VFL have no option to align one view to superview not that I am aware.

Below Code will create image with 50 width 50 height and
center to Y

```
let centerY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: personImage,
                                    attribute: .centerY,
                                    relatedBy: .equal,
                                       toItem: self,
                                    attribute: .centerY,
                                   multiplier: 1.0,
                                     constant: 0.0);
        self.addConstraint(centerY);
```

set height 50 as well

```
 constrains.append(contentsOf: NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[personImage(==50)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
```

add leading padding of 10 to superview set width 50 as well

```
constrains.append(contentsOf: NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-[personImage(==50)]", options: [.alignAllCenterY], metrics: nil, views: views))
```